# how to get the value from the tag for change css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The data is obtained in the template in this way (python / jango), as a result the number of tags p with the class, the data from which are extracted, changes dynamically

My html:

```
{% for product in items %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ product.item_title }}</p>
            <p class="product-quantity">{{ product.quantity }}</p>
            <p>{{ product.price }}</p>
       </li>
{% endfor %}
```

My js:

```
var quantity_block = $('.product-quantity'),
    quantity_number = parseInt(quantity_block.text());
console.log(quantity_number);

if (quantity_number < 10) {
    quantity_block.css(
        {'background-color': 'red'}
    )
}
```

but this condition will never be fulfilled, since I have this selector the same for 6 p tags, and the values come from the database (2, 4, 15, 3 ....) and they are concatenated - 24153, I get such a number on the output .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('.product-quantity').each(function () {
    var quantity_block = $(this),
        quantity_number = parseInt(quantity_block.text());

    if (quantity_number < 10) {
        quantity_block.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Or [`.css( propertyName, function )`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

```
$('.product-quantity').css('background-color', function (index, oldValue) {
    var quantity_number = parseInt($(this).text());

    return quantity_number < 10 ? 'red' : oldValue;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `quantity_block` contains **collection** of elements. Thus, you need to iterate the elements of this collection using [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method. Try to use following

```js
$('.product-quantity').each(function() {
  var quantity_number = parseInt($(this).text());
  console.log(quantity_number);
  if (quantity_number < 10) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="product-quantity">7</p>
<p class="product-quantity">15</p>
<p class="product-quantity">8</p>
```